# Center support and bearing replacement

Tags: truck, plymouth

My 1980 Plymouth Arrow truck engine and transmission have been changed to a Nissan Z24 engine with manual transmission. My question is I ordered the center support bearing for a Plymouth Arrow Truck. Was that correct or should I have ordered for a Nissan Z24? I do not know if they changed the rear end. I kind of doubt it.

Comment: Do you mean the center support and bearing for the driveshaft? What driveshaft (Plymouth or Nissan) is on the modified vehicle?

Comment: In my question it says, I ordered for a Plymouth Arrow and above that, it said my Arrow, yes, the center support bearing is for a driveshaft.

Comment: You do not say whether the driveshaft came from the Plymouth, or from the Nissan. It's very likely the driveshafts and the center bearings from these two manufacturers are different. Whether the Plymouth center support bearing you already have is correct cannot be said without knowing what driveshaft is on the vehicle.

Comment: your right I didnt say it because I can't possibly know. My truck is a Plymouth. Can they change the drive shaft and center support without changing the rear end?

Comment: It doesnt look to me like this rear end has been changed, is why I ask.

Comment: The rear end is not the driveshaft; the driveshaft is the big metal tube that connects the transmission to the differential/rear axle; the differential/rear axle is often called "the rear end." The driveshaft might be original Plymouth, or it might be from Nissan; we still don't know which manufacturer made the driveshaft. The correct center support and bearing will come from the same manufacturer as the driveshaft.

Comment: I understand that.... and it is not a tube....it is a driveshaft and their are two of them, hence a Center Support Bearing is needed.

Comment: Well... _which manufacturer made the driveshaft?_ I have asked this question four times. You may not know, but the fellow who did the work will know. He either used the driveshaft that was on the Plymouth Arrow before he began work, or he took that driveshaft off and replaced it with another driveshaft, presumably from Nissan. Without knowing that, no one can say what the correct center bearing and support might be. That the truck's rear end is the same suggests  the Plymouth driveshaft was retained, but it may have been changed, and none of us can know which driveshaft was actually used.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. I have not intended to offend. I have read your comments and questions carefully; the closest I can come to an answer is "A rear end from the original Plymouth car suggests that the driveshaft is also from Plymouth. On the other hand, it'd be easier to connect the new Nissan transmission to a Nissan driveshaft. I have no knowledge of where the driveshaft came from, and so no idea whether a Plymouth center bearing/support is called for, or whether a Nissan center bearing/support is called for. Perhaps someone else will comment and provide you with more information.

Comment: Thank you. That was a great answer. I dont have that knowledge either. Your answer however has helped.

Comment: Voted to close, as without the information David requested, we cannot give an accurate answer. You need to find out from whoever did the work. Also Lavadoras, I am flagging your comments for rudeness - David was asking for essential information - you have no excuse to be rude like that to someone trying to help you.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks for the support. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If the mounting flanges are part of the bearing assembly, it's likely the original Plymouth Arrow Truck (Mitsubishi Forte) carrier bearing assembly.

If the mounting flange is a separate "saddle" piece, it's more likely from the Nissan drivetrain.

You can buy *both* of them for less than $30, and return the one that doesn't fit.